# Notebook widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, wxpython, tabs, tkinter

Having played around a little with both Tkinter and wxPython, I like Tkinter much better in terms of how clean my source code looks.  However, it doesn't seem to have as many features; in particular it doesn't have tabs (as in, the tabs at the top of a Firefox window).

A little Googling on the subject offers a few suggestions.  There's [a cookbook entry](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/188537/) with a class allowing you to use tabs, but it's very primitive.  There's also [Python megawidgets](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge, although this seems very old and gave me errors during installation.

Does anyone have experience making tabbed GUIs in Tkinter?  What did you use?  Or is it simply the case that anyone who needs more powerful windowing components has to use wxPython?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On recent Python (> 2.7) versions, you can use the [`ttk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html) module, which provides access to the *Tk themed widget* set, which has been introduced in `Tk 8.5`.

Here's how you import `ttk` in Python 2:

```
import ttk

help(ttk.Notebook)
```

In Python 3, the [`ttk`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tkinter.ttk.html?highlight=ttk#module-tkinter.ttk) module comes with the standard distributions as a submodule of [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tkinter.html).

Here's a simple working example based on an example from the [`TkDocs`](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html) website:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


def demo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("ttk.Notebook")

    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

    # adding Frames as pages for the ttk.Notebook 
    # first page, which would get widgets gridded into it
    page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)

    # second page
    page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    text = ScrolledText(page2)
    text.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    nb.add(page1, text='One')
    nb.add(page2, text='Two')

    nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

Another alternative is to use the `NoteBook` widget from the [`tkinter.tix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html) library. To use `tkinter.tix`, you must have the `Tix` widgets installed, usually alongside your installation of the `Tk` widgets. To test your installation, try the following:

```
from tkinter import tix
root = tix.Tk()
root.tk.eval('package require Tix')
```

For more info, check out this [webpage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html) on the PSF website.

Note that `tix` is pretty old and not well-supported, so your best choice might be to go for `ttk.Notebook`.

Comment: Sadly, I get an error when I try to use the Tix.NoteBook class on my Windows box.  This does look like the way to go if I ever decide to use Tkinter for anything major, but the effort of compiling everything from source would be prohibitive for a small project.

Comment: Actually I figured it out on my own; the number of Python Tix resources online is distressingly low, and I'll probably post a Stack Overflow question about that if nothing else.  Thanks again for the suggestion to use Tix.

Comment: tix is pretty old and not very well supported. The best solution going forward is ttk.Notebook. Starting with tk version 8.5 there are themed widgets (ttk) which includes a notebook.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone still looking, I have got this working as Tab in tkinter. Play around with the code to make it function the way you want (for example, you can add button to add a new tab):

```
from tkinter import *

class Tabs(Frame):

    """Tabs for testgen output"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Tabs, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.curtab = None
        self.tabs = {}
        self.addTab()                
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    def addTab(self):
        tabslen = len(self.tabs)
        if tabslen < 10:
            tab = {}
            btn = Button(self, text="Tab "+str(tabslen), command=lambda: self.raiseTab(tabslen))
            btn.grid(row=0, column=tabslen, sticky=W+E)

            textbox = Text(self.parent)
            textbox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S, in_=self)

            # Y axis scroll bar
            scrollby = Scrollbar(self, command=textbox.yview)
            scrollby.grid(row=7, column=5, rowspan=2, columnspan=1, sticky=N+S+E)
            textbox['yscrollcommand'] = scrollby.set

            tab['id']=tabslen
            tab['btn']=btn
            tab['txtbx']=textbox
            self.tabs[tabslen] = tab
            self.raiseTab(tabslen)

    def raiseTab(self, tabid):
        print(tabid)
        print("curtab"+str(self.curtab))
        if self.curtab!= None and self.curtab != tabid and len(self.tabs)>1:
                self.tabs[tabid]['txtbx'].lift(self)
                self.tabs[self.curtab]['txtbx'].lower(self)
        self.curtab = tabid


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x450+300+300")
    t = Tabs(root)
    t.addTab()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: modern versions of tkinter come with the `ttk` package, which has a native tab widget. There's no reason to build your own anymore. See http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html#notebook

Comment: Ohh, I should have looked more into this. I needed to use tkinter for distribution and did not think tab was a part of it. Ohh well, it was fun making it myself but I guess I will end up using ttk package for better support :P. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

While it may not help you at the moment, tk 8.5 comes with an extended set of widgets. This extended set is available with tk 8.4 by way of an extension known as "tile". Included in the extended set of widgets is a notebook widget. Unfortunately, at this time Tkinter by default uses a fairly old version of Tk that doesn't come with these widgets.

There have been efforts to make tile available to Tkinter. Check out http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TileWrapper. For another similar effort see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttk. Also, for a taste of how these widgets look (in Ruby, Perl and Tcl) see http://www.tkdocs.com/.

Tk 8.5 is a *huge* improvement over stock Tk. It introduces several new widgets, native widgets, and a theming engine. Hopefully it will be available by default in Tkinter some day soon. Too bad the Python world is lagging behind other languages.

*update: The latest versions of Python now include support for the themed widgets out of the box. _*

Comment: Sweet!  I'll definitely check this out.  Thanks, and I definitely agree about Python lagging behind other languages at GUI stuff; I guess the problem is that it's so often used for web programming and other server/scripting software that GUI work just isn't a priority for most developers.

Answer (score 0):

"Or is it simply the case that anyone who needs more powerful windowing components has to use wxPython?"
Short answer: yes.

Long answer:
It may take some practice for your wxPython code to feel "clean," but it is nicer and much more powerful than Tkinter.  You will also get better support, since more people use it these days.

Comment: "Much nicer" is definitely subjective. With the latest versions of Tkinter which includes the themed widgets, Tkinter looks as modern as any other cross platform toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

What problems did you have with pmw?  It's old, yes, but it's pure python so it should work.

Note that Tix doesn't work with py2exe, if that is an issue for you.

Comment: My problem was that the setup.py script didn't work.  I later installed it by simply copying the Pmw directory into site-packages.  But this kind of error combined with the oldness of the package makes me reluctant to use it.  At least wxPython is current, although I still like Tkinter better.