# Two plots, each on its own page in tkinter

Tags: python, plot, tkinter

I have two plots, which I get as a result of some calculations. I want to show each of them on a separate page. I wanted to use the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284234/notebook-widget-in-tkinter), but I don't know where to insert the code of my plots.

Below is the code for one of the graphs. For the second it is similar.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

lf = ttk.Labelframe(root, text='Plot №1')
lf.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nwes', padx=3, pady=3)

fig = Figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df.plot(x='date', y=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4','col5'], ax=ax)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=lf)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

And one more question, how can I show some values in each window for the corresponding plot? For example, on the page for the first plot, I need to show some three values, say

```
value1 = 5
value2 = 10 
value3 = 15
```

I need to show them next to the corresponding plot.

Any advice, please?

Comment: Your code had error: `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`

Comment: @saul I define my dataframe before, I take data from the Excel file.