# Python error trying to use Tab Control: Tkinter has no attribute Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tabs

I am trying to add a tab control to my GUI. However I'm getting this error: AttributeError: module tkinter has no attribute 'Notebook'. Other Tkinter objects work just fine, such as buttons, labels, canvas.

Any ideas what would cause this?

Also see same in REPL:

```python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.notebook()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'notebook'
>>> tkinter.Notebook()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Notebook'
```

Here's my code:

```python
import tkinter as tk

class Tab1():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.tabControl = tk.Notebook(self.frame)
```

I installed newer version of Python, and get same result:

```html
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.Notebook()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Notebook'
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: tkinter doesn't have a notebook. The ttk module does, however.

Comment: Bryan, thank you. None of the examples I had reviewed explained that Notebook was part of ttk which is a submodule of tkinter. They just used ttk so I had assumed it was the name they used when importing tkinter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ttk is a submodule of tkinter; it needed to be imported. Better example to review than those I previously used: 
[Notebook widget in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284234/notebook-widget-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

It's because Notebook Widgets do not belong to Tkinter module. You need to import it from Tkinter. ttk. for example -

`from Tkinter import ttk`

`ttk.notebook(root)`...
and so on